# Laravel com JWT não autentica por header

Tags: php, json, laravel, jwt

Estou utilizando o **Laravel 5.3** junto com o **JWT**, porém quando envio a autenticação pelo **header** ele me retorna que não estou autenticado e se encaminho o token por **parâmetro** ele me exibe o resultado, segue meu .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Aqui está o service que foi criado para adicionar o Bearer em todas requisições para as APIs,

```
function authService($q, $location) {
    return {
        getToken     : getToken,
        setToken     : function (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        },
        request      : function (config) {
            var url = config.url;
            if (url.indexOf('../../../../api/') > -1) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 401){
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };

    function getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }
}
```

Alguém já passou por este caso antes? se eu tentar acessar todas as APIs por localhost funciona mais na web ele fica dizendo que não está autenticada mas se passo **www.example.com.br?token={token}** ele funciona

Comment: Você está usando algum pacote?

Comment: Estou utilizando este pacote https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth, estanho é que em localhost funciona normalmente, mas na web não.

Comment: no console do navegador não está aparecendo algum erro, você já observou isso (pressione F12 e verifique na guia console e network se tem algum erro)?

Comment: se eu enviar via get http://teste.com.br/api/usuario com o Authorization no header ele aparece { "error":"Unauthenticated." } agora se eu envio http://teste.com.br/api/usuario?token={token} ele funciona normalmente

Comment: Jean seu código do angular pode está errado! e por isso ele não deve esta enviando o header corretamente, por isso eu pedi para você olhar com F12 no console se ele envia, estou já achando que não... vou dar uma olhada numa app que fiz e te falo.

Comment: Certo então, aguardo e muito obrigado!

Comment: Poxa pelo seu ultimo comentário parece que é enviado o `authorization` estranho mesmo.

Comment: No meu código eu tenho um `factory` que se chama-se `$authorization`, na linha para colocar a authorization e enviar seria: `$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = $authorization.token();` dentro de `$authorization.token()` é `return "bearer " + $cookies.get("Authorization");` que guardo ele em um `cookie` funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Exatamente, o meu está do mesmo jeito porém ele não funciona somente se eu encaminhar o token por parâmetro, parece que o apache não está reconhecendo o Header da request